# 15 Puzzle Game JavaScript

Tags: javascript, game, canvas, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have created a program that lets you play the fifteen puzzle game. You have to get the blocks into ascending order by moving them into the one open space. I would like some feedback on the code and how I made it. This works best in full screen mode.

```js
"use strict";

class Block {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, value) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.value = value;
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.value) {
      let padding = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
      ctx.font = (this.w / 4).toString() + "px Georgia";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#7d4b1488";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x + padding, this.y + padding, this.w - padding, this.h - padding);
      ctx.strokeRect(this.x + padding, this.y + padding, this.w - padding, this.h - padding);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.fillText(this.value.toString(), this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.h / 2, width * 0.75);
    }
  }

  collidePoint(x, y) {
    return (
      x > this.x &&
      x < this.x + this.w &&
      y > this.y &&
      y < this.y + this.h
    );
  }

  sendTo(position) {
    moving++;
    let pos = {
      x: position.x,
      y: position.y,
    }
    let vel = {
      x: (this.x - pos.x) / 10,
      y: (this.y - pos.y) / 10,
    }
    let self = this;
    let n = 0;
    let movement = () => {
      drawAll();
      self.x -= vel.x;
      self.y -= vel.y;
      if (n >= 10) {
        self.x = pos.x;
        self.y = pos.y;
        moving--;
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(movement, 15);
        n++;
      }
    };
    setTimeout(movement, 15);
  }
}

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    let newI = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[newI];
    array[newI] = temp;
  }
}

function isValidNeighbor(ind1, ind2) {
  let pos1 = toNested(ind1);
  let pos2 = toNested(ind2);
  let dist1 = Math.abs(pos1[0] - pos2[0]);
  let dist2 = Math.abs(pos1[1] - pos2[1]);
  if (!dist1 || !dist2) {
    if (dist1 === 1 || dist2 === 1) {
      return dist1 !== dist2;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function toNested(index) {
  return [ index % boardSize, Math.floor(index / boardSize) ];
}

function findZero() {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
    if (board[i].value === 0) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function win() {
  if (!moving) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.font = "50px Georgia";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText(`You won in ${moves} ${moves === 1 ? "move" : "moves"}!`, width / 2, height / 2);
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.reload();
    }, 2500);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(win, 150);
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  board.forEach(block => {
    block.draw();
  });
}

function update() {
  drawAll();
  if (checkWin()) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      canvas.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
      setTimeout(win, 1000);
    }, 200);
  }
  document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = "Moves: " + moves.toString();
}

function checkWin() {
  let noZ = board.slice(0);
  noZ.splice(findZero(), 1);
  for (let i = 1; i < noZ.length; ++i) {
    if (noZ[i].value < noZ[i - 1].value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("display");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;
let boardSize;
let board;
let moves;
let moving;

function init() {
  moving = 0;
  boardSize = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  if (boardSize < 2 || boardSize > 5 || isNaN(boardSize)) {
    boardSize = 4;
  }
  board = Array.from(Array(boardSize ** 2).keys());
  moves = 0;
  shuffle(board);
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
    let pos = toNested(i);
    let w = width / boardSize;
    let h = height / boardSize;
    board[i] = new Block(pos[0] * w, pos[1] * h, w, h, board[i]);
  }
  update();
}

function handleClick(e) {
  if (!moving) {
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
      if (board[i].collidePoint(e.clientX - rect.x, e.clientY - rect.y)) {
        let zIndex = findZero();
        if (isValidNeighbor(i, zIndex)) {
          moves++;
          let tempPos = {
            x: board[i].x,
            y: board[i].y,
          };
          board[i].sendTo(board[zIndex]);
          board[zIndex].sendTo(tempPos);
          let temp = board[i];
          board[i] = board[zIndex];
          board[zIndex] = temp;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    update();
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = init;
init();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fac4af;
  font-family: Georgia;
}

#board {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://15-puzzle-game--joyalmathew.repl.co/board.jpeg");
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 20px #9b857a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#display {
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: right;
}

#menu {
  display: grid;
  font-size: 15pt;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu p {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#menu input, #menu button {
  font-family: Georgia;
}

#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>15 Puzzle Game</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">
      <canvas id="display" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      <div id="menu">
        <div id="content">
          <p id="moves">Moves: </p><br><br>
          <p>Try getting the blocks into ascending order: left to right, top to bottom.</p>
          <p>Click any block next to the space to swap them.</p>
          <br>
          Size: <input id="size" type="number" min="2" max="5" value="4">
          <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing job! Very fun game to play! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Foreword

Your code is quite decent.  However, I did make a general outline of how I would probably implement a `Board` to improve readability.  Don't feel the need to take my suggestion.  The major changes I made to the code is CSS and HTML restructuring.  Additionally, I made modifications to accommodate different window sizes better.  The updated code is at the bottom.  I know that the topic of resizing can be difficult, so I wrote up the example.

Major JavaScript changes are not implemented (although some minor are) but are outlined inside the **JavaScript Structure Changes** section.

## Scaling problem

Your code seems to scale oddly at different dimensions.  I fixed that by assigning `canvas.width` to `Math.min(window.innerWidth - 40, 500)` to accomodate for smaller windows.  I also changed where you set the width/height of the `#menu` to `#board` becuase it looked better.  I also changed it to `max-width` to accommodate smaller game boards better.  It didn't make much sense to set a `max-height` as that is relative (depending on the size of `#menu`).

## CSS Structure changes

I removed `#content` it seemed erroneous and just completely removed `margin:auto` except for in `body`.

To increase DRYness I moved all `font-family: Georgia` to one selector.

```
#menu input, #menu button, body {
  font-family: Georgia;
}
```

I added a spacer between menu and the game because it looked better (`maring-top`)  I removed `display:grid` for `#menu` because when I removed `#content` it did not perform properly.

## JavaScript Structure Changes

I liked most of your JavaScript; however, I find that allowing on-the-fly dimension changes to be important when programming a 2d game like this.  So, I added a `window.addEventListener` to your code and had to make some minor changes to your class.

This is more of a band-aid solution, however.  Optimally, the `Block` class's x and y should have very little to do with drawing.  `Block.draw` would simply store how it should be drawn based on some values given (like x, y, w, h).  Then `Board.draw` would loop through `Block`s and invoke `Block.draw`.  `Board` would manage location information.

More of a style thing, but I prefer:

```
let pos = toNested(i),
    w = width / boardSize,
    h = height / boardSize;
```

over having lots of let's pile up in my code:

```
let pos = toNested(i);
let w = width / boardSize;
let h = height / boardSize;
```

Some people prefer to use `let`, that's fine.  `var` can be used where it does not matter when changes occur after the control block is over.  `let` saves the head ache so I understand the choice.

Board is implemented as an array.  You could probably benefit a little from turning it into a class.  From there, instead of:

```
let temp = board[i];
board[i] = board[zIndex];
board[zIndex] = temp;
```

You could invoke something like `board.swap`.  This change would improve readability in `handleClick` and `shuffle`, as you are creating clearly defined functions: one for each purpose.  You could also add easy functions like `moveUp` or `moveDown`... etc.

It would be preferred to have a `Board.collision` that returns first collision with a block (there should only be one...).  It would prevent `handleClick` from having to perform both collision detection and board swapping and movement checks.

I would prefer to use a 2D array within the `Board` class instead of `toNested`, it would make code more readable. I liked that you decided to just make that a function.  However, it isn't as great as a simple 2d array.

It would probably also be easier to store the location of the empty square.  I liked your decision to have be a `0` tile.  Very clever way to work with an array.  But it may be simpler to leave it as a `null` inside a 2d array in `Board`.

When swapping, it would be simpler to use `Board.draw` and then swapping them inside of the 2d array, just my opinion.  Then having `Board.draw` set up how where to draw each tile.

Having a `Board` class would also help you encapsulate a lot of the erroneous draw functions scattered in global namespace.  I typically make a `Game` class which is responsible for invoking appropriate draw functions, but in a game this small, I think you could incorporate it inside of `Board`.

```js
"use strict";

class Block {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  setDrawSettings(x, y , w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.value) {
      let padding = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
      ctx.font = (this.w / 4).toString() + "px Georgia";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#7d4b1488";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x + padding, this.y + padding, this.w - padding, this.h - padding);
      ctx.strokeRect(this.x + padding, this.y + padding, this.w - padding, this.h - padding);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.fillText(this.value.toString(), this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.h / 2, width * 0.75);
    }
  }

  collidePoint(x, y) {
    return (
      x > this.x &&
      x < this.x + this.w &&
      y > this.y &&
      y < this.y + this.h
    );
  }

  sendTo(position) {
    moving++;
    let pos = {
      x: position.x,
      y: position.y,
    }
    let vel = {
      x: (this.x - pos.x) / 10,
      y: (this.y - pos.y) / 10,
    }
    let self = this;
    let n = 0;
    let movement = () => {
      drawAll();
      self.x -= vel.x;
      self.y -= vel.y;
      if (n >= 10) {
        self.x = pos.x;
        self.y = pos.y;
        moving--;
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(movement, 15);
        n++;
      }
    };
    setTimeout(movement, 15);
  }
}

function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    let newI = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[newI];
    array[newI] = temp;
  }
}

function isValidNeighbor(ind1, ind2) {
  let pos1 = toNested(ind1);
  let pos2 = toNested(ind2);
  let dist1 = Math.abs(pos1[0] - pos2[0]);
  let dist2 = Math.abs(pos1[1] - pos2[1]);
  if (!dist1 || !dist2) {
    if (dist1 === 1 || dist2 === 1) {
      return dist1 !== dist2;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function toNested(index) {
  return [ index % boardSize, Math.floor(index / boardSize) ];
}

function findZero() {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
    if (board[i].value === 0) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function win() {
  if (!moving) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.font = "50px Georgia";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillText(`You won in ${moves} ${moves === 1 ? "move" : "moves"}!`, width / 2, height / 2);
    setTimeout(() => {
      location.reload();
    }, 2500);
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(win, 150);
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  board.forEach(block => {
    block.draw();
  });
}

function update() {
  drawAll();
  if (checkWin()) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      canvas.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
      setTimeout(win, 1000);
    }, 200);
  }
  document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = "Moves: " + moves.toString();
}

function checkWin() {
  let noZ = board.slice(0);
  noZ.splice(findZero(), 1);
  for (let i = 1; i < noZ.length; ++i) {
    if (noZ[i].value < noZ[i - 1].value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const canvas = document.getElementById("display");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let width,
    height,
    boardSize,
    board,
    moves,
    moving;

//new
function setDimensions() {
  canvas.width = Math.min(window.innerWidth - 40, 500);
  canvas.height = Math.min(window.innerHeight - 20, 500);
  width = canvas.width;
  height = canvas.height;
}
setDimensions();

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  setDimensions();
  let w = width / boardSize,
      h = height / boardSize;
  setUpBoard(board);
  update();
});

function setUpBoard(board) {
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
    let pos = toNested(i),
        w = width / boardSize,
        h = height / boardSize;
    board[i].setDrawSettings(pos[0] * w, pos[1] * h, w, h);
  }
}

function init() {
  moving = 0;
  boardSize = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  if (boardSize < 2 || boardSize > 5 || isNaN(boardSize)) {
    boardSize = 4;
  }
  board = Array.from(Array(boardSize ** 2).keys());
  moves = 0;
  shuffle(board);
  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    board[i] = new Block(board[i]);
  }
  setUpBoard(board);
  update();
}

function handleClick(e) {
  if (!moving) {
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
      if (board[i].collidePoint(e.clientX - rect.x, e.clientY - rect.y)) {
        let zIndex = findZero();
        if (isValidNeighbor(i, zIndex)) {
          moves++;
          let tempPos = {
            x: board[i].x,
            y: board[i].y,
          };
          board[i].sendTo(board[zIndex]);
          board[zIndex].sendTo(tempPos);
          
          let temp = board[i];
          board[i] = board[zIndex];
          board[zIndex] = temp;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    update();
  }
}

canvas.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

document.getElementById("reset").onclick = init;
init();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

body {
  background-color: #fac4af;
  margin: auto;
}

#menu input, #menu button, body {
  font-family: Georgia;
}

#board {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://15-puzzle-game--joyalmathew.repl.co/board.jpeg");
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 20px #9b857a;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

#display {
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: right;
}

#menu {
  font-size: 15pt;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#menu p {
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>15 Puzzle Game</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">
      <canvas id="display" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      <div id="menu">
        <p id="moves">Moves: </p><br><br>
        <p>Try getting the blocks into ascending order: left to right, top to bottom.</p>
        <p>Click any block next to the space to swap them.</p>
        <br>
        Size: <input id="size" type="number" min="2" max="5" value="4">
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```